# While decrypt message using AES Algorithm Exception :Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption

I want to do decryption by using AES algorithm
My Code is as Follows :

```
public static String decrypt(String key, byte[] encrypted)
            throws GeneralSecurityException {

        byte[] raw = key.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        if (raw.length != 16) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key size.");
        }
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec,new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);

        return new String(original, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
    }
```

Why i am getting this Exception ???

Comment: Are you certain the program that did the encryption used an IV of all zeros? That is usually bad practice; unless the keys are always unique, the IVs must be unique and unpredictable per key, usually achieved by making them random, and must be sent along with the ciphertext and used when decrypting. A symmetric decryption error on PKCS5-padded data is caught as "bad padding" about 99.6% of the time, and gives randomish garbage data the rest.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : if i use AES/CBC/NoPadding then there is no such exception occurs

Comment: Yes, if you tell it not to check padding it can't find a padding or decryption error even if there is one. If you decrypt with NoPadding do you get the correct data -- especially for data at least 17 bytes long? If not, then as @Ebbe says either the mode, key or IV is wrong. Of those three, your zero IV looks the most suspect to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AES** is a block cipher that encrypts in blocks of 16 bytes. The padding is used to pad messages so they have a size that is a multiple of 16 bytes. **PKCS-5** padding determines the number of bytes missing to be a multiple of 16, and then writes this number repeatable until sufficiently padded.

So a message like this (in hex):

```
D1 F2 05 7E 97 54 27 89 F2
```

would be padded like

```
D1 F2 05 7E 97 54 27 89 F2 07 07 07 07 07 07 07 
                           --------------------  pad
```

When decrypting the message it is checked that the padding is correct. If not, something have gone wrong.

### Typical causes:

Usually when padding is wrong, the whole decrypt have gone wrong. Using NoPadding in the decrypt would only remove the symptoms - not cure the problem.

All the following things can trigger a padding exception:

- Using wrong IV when decrypting
- Using wrong key when decrypting
- Using wrong chaining mode when decrypting (the CBC)
- Or using wrong padding mode (!)

Comment: nice explain !! it helps